# Office URI schemes, new file from template(nft) not saving the file in provided location

Tags: ms-word, office365, onedrive

We are creating a new file from template as specified in the Office [Uri Schemes documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes#new-document-from-template).

As per the documentation we can give an optional parameter with **|s** to specify the default path offered as a save location when the file is first saved. The only restriction is that if the optional default save location is supplied, it must be pointing to the same host name as the template.

We are using Office 365 group drive to save the template and the default save location(for newly generated file) is also in the same group drive. But it is not picking the default save location as specified.

Following is the URI that we are testing.

```
ms-word:nft|u|https://figg.sharepoint.com/sites/1dev/Shared%20Documents/Config/Files/Minutes.dotx|s|https://figg.sharepoint.com/sites/1dev/Shared%20Documents/Dest
```

The above url when opened generate a new file from template but it did not give the default save location specified in the command when we try to save the file.

Any help if how to fix this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your save URL ? It looks truncated as Dest...
If it's correct, make sure that it ends with a forward slash, like this:

[ms-word:nft|u|https://figg.sharepoint.com/sites/1dev/Shared%20Documents/Config/Files/Minutes.dotx|s|https://figg.sharepoint.com/sites/1dev/Shared%20Documents/Dest/](http://ms-word:nft%7Cu%7Chttps://figg.sharepoint.com/sites/1dev/Shared%20Documents/Config/Files/Minutes.dotx%7Cs%7Chttps://figg.sharepoint.com/sites/1dev/Shared%20Documents/Dest/)

You also must make sure you have the correct permissions to write back to that particular document library

HTH

Comment: All permissions are right, I am a group owner so  have full access on the drive. The url is also correct but still it does not works. Tried both with and without trailing / in the destination